# opening and reading all the files in a directory in python - python beginner

Tags: python

I'd like to read the contents of every file in a folder/directory and then print them at the end (I eventually want to pick out bits and pieces from the individual files and put them in a separate document)
So far I have this code

```
import os
path = 'results/'
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for i in fileList:
    file = open(os.path.join('results/'+ i), 'r')
allLines = file.readlines()
print(allLines)
```

at the end I dont get any errors but it only prints the contents of the last file in my folder in a series of strings and I want to make sure its reading every file so I can then access the data I want from each file. I've looked online and I cant find where I'm going wrong. Is there any way of making sure the loop is iterating over all my files and reading all of them?

also i get the same result when I use

```
 file = open(os.path.join('results/',i), 'r')
```

in the 5th line

Please help I'm so lost
Thanks!!

Comment: when opening files, especially when opening multiple files, you should use a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement

Answer (score 5):

- Separate the different functions of the thing you want to do.
- Use generators wherever possible. Especially if there are a lot of files or large files

#### Imports

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
```

#### Deciding which files to process:

```
source_dir = Path('results/')

files = source_dir.iterdir()
```

#### [Optional] Filter files

For example, if you only need files with extension `.ext`

```
files = source_dir.glob('*.ext')
```

#### Process files

```
def process_files(files):
    for file in files:
        with file.open('r') as file_handle :
            for line in file_handle:
                # do your thing
                yield line
```

#### Save the lines you want to keep

```
def save_lines(lines, output_file=sys.std_out):
    for line in lines:
        output_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot indentation at this line `allLines = file.readlines()` 
and maybe you can try that :

```
import os

allLines = []
path = 'results/'
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for file in fileList:
   file = open(os.path.join('results/'+ i), 'r')
   allLines.append(file.read())
print(allLines)
```

Comment: when I do that I get an error message
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 27: invalid start byte

Comment: What is the type of file that you want to open ? and maybe you can try to decode it with 'latin-1' sometimes it works. keep me in touch

Comment: I get name 'i' is not defined error and do not see i is initialized, looks like this code needs an update?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to indent this line `allLines.append(file.read())`.
Because it was outside the loop, it only appended the `file` variable to the list *after* the `for` loop was finished. So it only appended the last value of the `file` variable that remained after the loop. Also, you should not use `readlines()` in this way. Just use `read()` instead;

```
import os

allLines = []
path = 'results/'
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for file in fileList:
   file = open(os.path.join('results/'+ i), 'r')
   allLines.append(file.read())
print(allLines)
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply! when I indent it like that I get an error message for line 9 and line 321 (which i dont understand) and it says: nicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 27: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

This also creates a file containing all the files you wanted to print.

```
rootdir= your folder, like 'C:\\Users\\you\\folder\\'
import os
f = open('final_file.txt', 'a')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):  
    for filename in files:
        data = open(full_name).read()
            f.write(data + "\n")                 
f.close()
```

This is a similar case, with more features: [Copying selected lines from files in different directories to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178453/copying-selected-lines-from-files-in-different-directories-to-another-file/47204259#47204259)